# CKEDITOR rich text area is not visible in IE10

Tags: ckeditor

I am using ckediotr rich text area, it is working fine in chrome whereas on IE 10 the rich text area is not visible.What can be the issue ??

```
CKEDITOR.replace('TextArea', { removeButtons: 'Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Anchor,Styles,Specialchar' });
```

Comment: Any particular version? How are you calling it?

Comment: On click of button i am calling jquery function and showing the rich text box :
CKEDITOR.replace('TextArea', { removeButtons: 'Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Anchor,Styles,Specialchar' });
And version is 4.4.5

Comment: What's not working about it though?